# How to configure MySql NET Connector with SSH (having a working connection in MySql Workbench)

Tags: c#, mysql, mysql-workbench, database-connection

**EDIT:** Solution found - details to be found below.

I have a configured connection in MySql Workbench which works fine, but when I try to connect using C# in Visual Studio, the connection reaches timeout. I increased it (just to be sure it ain't it), but without success.

Following the documentation, I used such code for testing:

```
        var builder = new MySqlConnectionStringBuilder();
        builder.UserID = userName;
        builder.Password = password;
        builder.Server = ipAddress;
        builder.SshHostName = sshIpAddress;
        builder.SshUserName = sshUserName;
        builder.SshPassword = sshPassword;
        builder.PersistSecurityInfo = true;
        builder.ConnectionTimeout = 60;
        builder.UseCompression = true;
        using (var connection = new MySqlConnection(builder.ConnectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();
            connection.Close();
        }
```

What am I missing? I checked on another DB that doesn't require SSH and it works fine, so I'm sure the provider is ok. In fact (from one of the screenshots) I didn't know how to translate 'use compression protocol' and 'ssh compression level = 0' to C# code. Can it be the gamechanger?

Here are snapshots of how workbench is configured:

[Main server settings (orange lines indicates provided data)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fx4Qz.png)

[Advanced tab -> 'Use compression protocol' and 'SSH compression level' are tricky](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w7HUH.png)

[Remote management tab - I don't know if it's relevant for my case](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HNuiy.png)

**EDIT:** The issue has been solved by using PuTTy and setting up SSH IP for tunnel and DB IP for the intended connection. Then inside of Visual Studio I could use MySqlConnection. The obvious difference was that now I had to provide 'localhost' as the DB server IP and use it without SSH there, so only username and password for DB were required.

Comment: Try updating the Net driver : https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/.  Last link do you have SSH selected?

Comment: I've got the last stable version from NuGet, downloaded today.
In the last link I've got 'Do not use remote management' chosen and it works that way in Workbench.

Comment: You have to check the connection strings to see what driver Workbench is using and c# (builder.ConnectionString) is using.  I do not know what driver MySqlConnectionStringBuilder uses.